# Show that $||a||_{\infty} \leq ||A||_{\infty} \leq n\cdot ||a||_{\infty}$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n × n}$ and $||A||_{\infty} = \max_{i=1,..,n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|$. Show that :

$$||a||_{\infty} \leq ||A||_{\infty} \leq n\cdot ||a||_{\infty}$$

where $a \in \mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}$ is obtained with the components of $A$ line by line.

To show that $||a||_{\infty} \leq ||A||_{\infty}$, I wanted to say that $||a||_{\infty}$ is just equal to the *max* of $A$ and so it's obviously $\leq$ $\max_{i=1,..,n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|$.
 But it's not so obvious because with the matrix $A =\begin{pmatrix} 0
 & 12 \\ 3
 & 11
\end{pmatrix}$, we have $||a||_{\infty} = 12$ and $||A||_{\infty}=14$ but the maximum value of A isn't on the maximum line ($||A||_{\infty}$). I don't know how to do a real proof of that..

And for the second inequality I have no idea.

Comment: Can you proof following: $\max_j |c_j| \le \sum_j |c_j|$?

Comment: Yeah a number is obviously smaller than himself + others

Comment: We have the equality when all other elements are 0

Comment: So what exactly bother you at $\|a\|_\infty \le \|A\|_\infty$?

Comment: Because the indice i can sometimes not be the same for both sides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first inequality: For every $i$, the sum $$S_{i} = \sum_{j=1}^{n}|a_{ij}|$$
is at least as big as each of its terms, so for all $i,j$ we have $S_{i} \ge |a_{ij}|$. But obviously, if we take the biggest one, $S = \max_{i}S_{i}$, then for all $i,j$ we have $S \ge S_{i} \ge |a_{ij}|$. This shows $S=||A||_{\infty}$ is bigger than $|a_{ij}|$ for every $i,j$, and hence bigger than $\max_{i,j}|a_{ij}| = ||a||_{\infty}$.

For the second inequality, no matter which line gives the maximum, every term in the sum is an element $|a_{ij}|$, and hence at most as big as $||a||_{\infty} = \max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$. But there are $n$ terms in the sum, so the whole sum is at most as big as $n||a||_{\infty}$.

Comment: But the vector a is one dimensional and n^2 length so there's a bit to change but np and thanks !

Comment: We can say simply say that every element $a_{ij} \in a $

Comment: I don't see the distinction you seem to be making - my argument does not depend on whether the $a_{ij}$ are elements of a matrix, vector or whatever, but if you understand the inequality then that's good.